# Flash (LSO) cookies count differrs on Firefox Better Privacy and Nirsoft Flash Cookies View

Tags: flash, cookies

The "[Better Privacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/betterprivacy/)" extension for Firefox says I have 22 [LSO cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) on my system. Nirsoft's [Flash Cookie View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/flash_cookies_view.html) says I have 9. Which one is correct?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Privacy points to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia by default, and Flash Cookie View scans for LSO cookies on C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects, which excludes what Better Privacy calls a "settings LSO".

[image]

If you set Flash Cookie View to scan C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia you will get the same LSO object count.